# SilverLight: how to align buttons in stackpanel center and right

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In the bottom "row" (inside of StackPanel with Horizontal orientation?) of my SilverLight control I would like to display two things:

1. "Save" button - to center-aligned
2. Text field with small text (kind of Version) - to be aligned to the right

How to do that? If I put both inside of stackpanel their alignement will be the same... Wrap panel just tie them together...

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Within your stack panel create a grid with 2 columns then align each column independantly.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Layout" Background="Black">
    <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Name="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" grid.column=1/>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Content="And me!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Button>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

No the perfect syntax but its just to demonstrate the idea.

Hope this helps!